# regex of two patterns

Tags: php, regex

I have a very large csv list, I've already converted a list into array and managed to fix a problem I was having with UTF8:

```
 $lines = file(''.get_template_directory_uri() . '/lines.csv');      

        foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line)
    {
        if(mb_detect_encoding($line, 'utf-8', false)) {
            $listLines.=  $line . '<br />';     
         }
    }
```

But all of the list items follow one of the two patterns below:

**Fist**

```
Adolfo (São Paulo)|Adolfo (SP)
```

Basically I need all content that is before `|`, output:

```
Adolfo_(São_Paulo)
```

**second**

other items in the list do not have `|`

```
Abatiá (PR)    
Abel Figueiredo (PA)
São Francisco de Assis do Piauí (PI)
```

I need output:

```
Abatiá
Abel_Figueiredo
São_Francisco_de_Assis_do_Piauí
```

I believe I'm going to have to use regex, but I'm a bit confused as to make the rule for both situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments... how about this:

```
$lines = file(''.get_template_directory_uri() . '/lines.csv');      

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line)
{
    if(mb_detect_encoding($line, 'utf-8', false)) {
        $exp = '';
        if(strpos($line, '|')!==FALSE){
            $exp = '/^(.+?)\s*\|/';
        }else{
            $exp = '/^(.+?)\s*\(/';
        }
        preg_match($exp, $line, $matches);
        if($matches){
             $line = $matches[1];
             $line = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $line);
             $listLines.=  $line . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sinal2013 but this is returning `Adolfo_(São_Paulo)|Adolfo_(SP)_`  and `São_Francisco_de_Assis_do_Piauí_(PI)_`

Comment: I've tried your update and all correspondences similar to `Adolfo_(São_Paulo)` are appearing correctly but matches similar to `São_Francisco_de_Assis_do_Piauí` are not appearing on the list

Comment: This is only showing matches that have `text_(text)` or similar with more words left or inside the parentheses

Comment: Ok...  thanks for letting me knw. I  think i know what's going on. But to simplify things, can it be done in 2 parts..  if | exist use expression 1 else use a next

Comment: Hey great. Thanks. Glad you got through with it.

Answer (score 1):

Check if "|" is present in the string. If it is present then split on the bar and get only the 1st substring. If its not present then split on spaces and get all substrings except the last one.

This should work for your list of data if the elements belong to either of the types mentioned and there are no 3rd type of strings